# C# chart rotate labels

Tags: c#, charts

I have a simple chart, and I'd like the labels on the x-axis to be rotated 45 degrees. What am I doing wrong?

```
Chart c = new Chart();
c.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
c.Width = 200;
c.Height = 200;
Series mySeries = new Series();
mySeries.Points.DataBindXY(new string[] { "one", "two", "three" }, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
mySeries.LabelAngle = 45; // why doesn't this work?
c.Series.Add(mySeries);
```

The output is:

[image: img]

I'm using the charting stuff from System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The documentation says that Series.LabelAngle sets data point label angle, which (I think) is a label above the chart's column.

To set an angle of axis labels try this one:

```
var c = Chart1;
c.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
c.Width = 200;
c.Height = 200;
Series mySeries = new Series();
mySeries.Points.DataBindXY(new string[] { "one", "two", "three" }, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
//mySeries.LabelAngle = -45; // why doesn't this work?
c.Series.Add(mySeries);
c.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45; // this works
```

Comment: I was trying to rotate the labels with area's object lately, that was not working. Appending chart object makes it work like a charm.

Answer (score 19):

Here is how I usually rotate my X Axis labels.

```
 ChartArea area = new ChartArea();
 area.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
 area.AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.LabelsAngleStep30;
 area.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;
```

Results

[image]

The key property/line to look at above is the "LabelAutoFitStyle".

Answer (score 3):

I needed these lines to get it to work:

```
chartarea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90;
chartarea.AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
chartarea.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
```

Comment: whoops, didn't read the 45 degree requirement, but it might help someone nonetheless...

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old and answered. I just want to say that Series.LabelAngle controls series' label, not Axis'. If you add these two lines, the label would be shown above the column and is rotated 45 degrees:

```
mySeries.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
mySeries.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```

So you have to set AxisX's LabelAngle as Maciej Rogoziński said.

Answer (score 0):

Axis.IsLabelAutoFit default value is true, so it must be set to false in order for LabelStyle.Angle to be applied.